# How to add CORS to Blazor Webassembly 3.2 preview

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I asked this question before using my code, but this is really a general question.  Blazor Webassembly 3.2 preview uses a new way to start the program from that does NOT use startup.cs or have a ConfigureServices function.  Everything is done from

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
```

So this is my version

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataLayer, DataLayer>();

    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => 
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
    });
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

What is the proper way to add CORS for 3.2 preview?

Thank you.

Comment: CORS is a browser feature that needs to be applied by the web servers that a browsers calls. WebAssembly runs in the browser. So you cannot set CORS policies on Blazor WebAssembly. This needs to be allowed on the server application you are calling.

Comment: I don't have access to the server I'm calling.  Are you saying it's impossible to use CORS with Webassembly unless you have access to the called domain?

Comment: There are ways to bypass this. For example you can put a proxy in between that has CORS settings to your web site.

Comment: I ran into the same issue.  If I put a proxy in, then all my calls to the other domain are coming from the same IP.  The API I am using does not allow CORS and rate limits by client.  You can also get around this by deploying your app wrapped in something like WebWindow or Electron for desktop and Uno for mobile.